# mix two insert with subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm inserting data into DB, there is

UnitChaine

```
[id],[FK_Unit],[DateIn],[DateOut]
```

And Personnal

```
[FK_VW_PERSONNAL],[FK_UnitChaine]
```

Here I have a list of FK_VW_PERSONNAL id's that are created and I have to insert them into Personnal and UnitChaine.

I cound insert UnitChains then get the id of inserted then create personnal:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[pstl_UnitChaine]
           ([FK_Unit]
           ,[DateIn]
           ,[DateOut])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,NOW
           ,NULL)
```

Then search for the [id] of inserted [pstl_UnitChaine] and insert new personnal :

```
INSERT INTO [Personnal]
           ([FK_VW_PERSONNAL]
           ,[FK_UnitChaine])
     VALUES
           (id from my list
           ,id I found from insert)
```

But I guess there is a quickest way to doing that and I'm not a SQL killer, so if you can diretct me / explian me something that could improove the pain of encoding, it would be marvellous :-)

**Edit :** 
After PaulFrancis proposal I have one issue:

```
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
```

second insert juste after the insert of [pstl_UnitChaine]:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Personnal] ([FK_VW_PERSONNAL].[FK_UnitChaine]) VALUES (2118, SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `IDENTITY`. Just make sure you `INSERT` of the UnitChaine, happens before executing this.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[pstl_UnitChaine]
       ([FK_Unit]
       ,[DateIn]
       ,[DateOut])
 VALUES
       (1
       ,NOW
       ,NULL)

INSERT INTO [Personnal]
       ([FK_VW_PERSONNAL]
       ,[FK_UnitChaine])
 VALUES
       (100
       ,SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` gets the Identity of the `INSERT`, that happened within the scope.

Comment: I've got this error : There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Please update your post with the Query you are using.

Comment: You are inserting only the FK ID `[FK_VW_PERS_AM].[FK_UnitChaine]` unless the `.` should actually be a `,`, then you should change it to `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Personnal] ([FK_VW_PERS_AM], [FK_UnitChaine]) VALUES 2118, SCOPE_IDENTITY())`

Comment: per-fect ! @PaulFrancis